# Wrong arity of simple function in clojure

Tags: function, clojure

I've started to learn clojure. In my book there is following exercise:

> Write a function, mapset, that works like map except the return value is a set:

```
(mapset inc [1 1 2 2])
; => #{2 3}
```

I've started with something like this:

```
(defn mapset
  [vect]
  (set vect))
```

The result is error

> "Wrong number of args (2) passed to: core/mapset"

I tried `[& args]` as well.

So, the question is: how can I solve such problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a closer look at your call to `mapset`:

```
(mapset inc [1 1 2 2])
```

Since code is data, this "call" is just a list of three elements:

1. The symbol `mapset`
2. The symbol `inc`
3. The vector `[1 1 2 2]`

When you evaluate this code, Clojure will see that it is a list and proceed to evaluate each of the items in that list (once it determines that it isn't a special form or macro), so it will then have a new list of three elements:

1. The function to which the symbol `core/mapset` was bound
2. The function to which the symbol `clojure.core/inc` was bound
3. The vector `[1 1 2 2]`

Finally, Clojure will *call* the first element of the list with the rest of the elements as arguments. In this case, there are *two* arguments in the rest of the list, but in your function definition, you only accounted for one:

```
(defn mapset
  [vect]
  (set vect))
```

To remedy this, you could implement `mapset` as follows:

```
(defn mapset
  [f vect]
  (set (map f vect)))
```

Now, when you call `(mapset inc [1 1 2 2])`, the argument `f` will be found to the function `clojure.core/inc`, and the argument `vect` will be bound to the vector `[1 1 2 2]`.

Comment: Damn it. This stuff really breaks a brain when you first deal with it. For some   reason I was thinking about `map` and this `mapset` like a data structure, not about that common for everybody map function. Such a shame :) Anyway, thank you for detailed answer

Answer (score 4):

Your definition of `mapset` takes a single argument `vect`

At a minimum you need to take 2 arguments, a function and a sequence

```
(defn mapset [f xs] (set (map f xs)))`
```

But it is interesting to think about this as the composition of 2 functions also:

```
(def mapset (comp set map))
```